# test several sftp / ftp hosts for connectivity

Tags: testing, ftp, sftp

I have a number of valid hosts that we need to test ftp and sftp connectivity with. This is for legitimate business purposes, we are authorized to connect to these hosts. This is a server conversion scenario where we're changing ip's and need to know which hosts are allowing/refusing connections. I have a list of hosts, and need to cycle through all of them and determine (1) if the host responds with a login banner and (2) if we can login successfully. Was wondering if this would be best done in perl/python/bash (which of these would be quickest to protoype with) or if there is anything already written that might speed development.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl and [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Net::OpenSSH::Parallel;

my @hosts = qw(localhost workload workload-db);

my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new();
$pssh->add_host($_) for @hosts;
$pssh->all(cmd => {stdout_file => "output-%HOST%",
                   stderr_to_stdout => 1,
                   stdin_file => ['-|', "echo uname -a\n"]});
$pssh->run;
my %errors = $pssh->get_errors;
print Dumper \%errors;
```